# GPvars in typo3

Tags: php, typo3

Can anyone tell me what is GPvars stands for in typo3 and what it contains and used for? Thanks!

Example

```
$this->GPvars['uid'] = intval( $this->GPvars['uid'] );
$this->GPvars['chash'] = substr( $this->GPvars['chash'], 0, 8 );
$this->GPvars['uid_author'] = intval( $this->GPvars['uid_author'] );
```

Comment: -1 for not even trying to use search engine: http://wiki.typo3.org/Backend_Programming#TYPO3_Project_Guidelines_and_.22GPvars.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G stands for `GET`, P stands for `POST`

It fetches 'uid' (for first example) from POST or from GET (POST has priority over GET)

I don't know where did you find this code, but I assume that's some kind of wrapper for [t3lib_div::_GP](http://typo3.org/api/typo3/classt3lib__div.html#a1645ccd6b4e63b9ac75e3020b67cd8c5), if I'm right the API in the link explains everything.